# Export CSV from QGIS without thousands separator

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, export, csv

I need to export a GeoPackage file from QGIS 3.2 as CSV file.
The GeoPackage contains two fields: UID as Integer and S_SCH as String (yes, it really is a string).
It looks like:

```
UID S_SCH
654321 0920056
1256897 0920058
```

When I export this as CSV, QGIS adds thousand separators to the Integer field:

```
UID S_SCH
654.321,0920056
1.256.897,0920058
```

How can I prevent QGIS from doing this? I need it as plain Integer without any separators, just like in the original GeoPackage.

Note this is about exporting a CSV from QGIS, not about importing as all the questions I found so far. Exporting a .csvt won't help here as long as there are still separators in the integer field.

Comment: Could you try a more recent version of QGIS? I don't seem to have this issue on v3.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't reproduce this behaviour with QGIS 3.4.8 ...
Nevertheless the separator (**in the .csv export**) appear when the "show thousand separator" checkbox is checked in **Options / General** ...

Comment: For QGIS 3.2 see [my own answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329423/107424). However, for newer versions this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can now confirm this is a **QGIS 3.2 specific bug**. This Problem does not exist in QGIS 2.18.15, 3.4.2 and 3.8.0.

The checkbox "Show thousands separator" in "Settings -> General" does not exist in QGIS 3.2. However, in newer versions unchecking it can solve this issue.